# Nesting a list within another list on the value it has

Tags: c#, sql, linq, list

I'm trying to add a nested list to another list where both ids are the same. The example as follows:

I have a main list that contains the foreign keys to other tables:

List PayslipMainlst = new List();

```
        PayslipMainlst.Add(new PayslipMain(0, "Grade 8 (Professional S)", "43", 45954.00, "Default Cost Centre", "TAX REF: 065/L11438", "There is no historic message stored for this payslip.", 1, 1, 1, 1));
        PayslipMainlst.Add(new PayslipMain(1, "Grade 8 (Professional S)", "43", 50000.00, "Default Cost Centre", "TAX REF: 065/L11608", "There is no historic message stored for this payslip.", 2, 2, 2, 2));
```

The last four values are the foreign keys, an example below shows how they are related:

List Deductionslst = new List();

```
        /* 28th September 2015 */
        Deductionslst.Add(new Deductions(1, "Tax Paid", "527.00", "3161.80"));
        Deductionslst.Add(new Deductions(1, "Employee NI", "301.72", "1810.32"));

        /*28th October 2015 */
        Deductionslst.Add(new Deductions(2, "Tax Paid", "590.50", "1400.20"));
        Deductionslst.Add(new Deductions(2, "Employee NI", "900.12", "5025.83"));
```

So the idea is to query one record from the PayslipMainlst list and the related tables would add in a nested list based on the foreign key.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Do you wish to find all deductions with an ID related to one found in a PaySlip? Is a deduction always related to a PaySlip? If so, redo that model. Favor composition so that each PaySlip object holds a reference to a list of possible deductions, as you are going to start the lookup of details from the PaySlip object. What is the reason for the list of deductions to exist separately?

Comment: Please post the `PayslipMain` class

Comment: Also, refrain from using the database lingo when talking code. You don't have foreign keys, you have properties or fields and nothing in that question is a "table".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) for grouping items by the same property:

Example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int,string>
{
   {1,"1"},
   {2,"1"},
   {3,"2"},
   {4,"2"},
   {5,"3"},
};

var grp = dict.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

The result is three groups:

1. The group with value "1" with keys: 1,2.
2. The group with value "2" with keys: 3,4.
3. The group with value "3" with keys: 5.

Comment: Not sure if i misinterpret the question, but i THINK that it is more a case of finding all listitems in different lists, that have an id as given by the properties in the PaySlip reference. If all items where stored on the same collection it could be handy, but it appears that it is several unconnected lists in this case... Or i am misreading the question.